# What is Blueprints from Unreal Engine from fundamentals of computer science?

Tags: computer-science, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to create something similar to Blueprints from Unreal but for Web development. I googled some questions about what Blueprint actually is but I didn't get any success, most of the links point to unrelated information.

I am trying to understand from fundamentals of computer science where Blueprint concept come from.

The only related information I got was this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming but I am not sure if Blueprints are actually this concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refer to it as a [Visual Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language) (note that it's actually also mentioned in the list of examples on that wikipedia page)

I'm not sure if the differences between VPL and FBP are really well defined. It could be said that FBP is more about asynchronous programming according to this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flow-based-programming/4HQ_tpeMJEE . In Blueprint you do take the order in which functions are called more into account. I suppose Blueprint is much closer to ''regular'' programming languages like C++ too in this regard

Comment: What is the differences between VPL and FBP? Sorry for my confusion because eventually FBP will finish in kind of VPL

Comment: @YordisPrietoLazo I'm not sure if the differences between the two are really well defined. It could be said that FBP is more about asynchronous programming according to this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flow-based-programming/4HQ_tpeMJEE . In Blueprint you do take the order in which functions are called more into account. I suppose Blueprint is much closer to ''regular'' programming languages like C++ too in this regard.

Comment: Can you add this in the answer so I can mark it as Answered please